# Can't get makefile to create executable

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that needs an executable, and i've followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r7i5X0rXJk&t , but i can't seem to get an executable.
I get all the o-files so i don't really get what's wrong

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -std=gnu11 -Wall

mmake: mmake.o parser.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o mmake parser.o mmake.o

parser.o: parser.c parser.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c parser.c

mmake.o: mmake.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c mmake.c
```

I've tried looking at other makefiles but they seem vastly more complex than mine so they don't help so much

My output below

```
gcc -g -std=gnu11 -Wall -c mmake.c
gcc -g -std=gnu11 -Wall -c parser.c
gcc -g -std=gnu11 -Wall -o mmake parser.o mmake.o
/usr/bin/ld: mmake.o: in function `parse_makefile':
/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:201: multiple definition of `parse_makefile'; parser.o:/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:201: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: mmake.o: in function `makefile_del':
/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:301: multiple definition of `makefile_del'; parser.o:/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:301: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: mmake.o: in function `makefile_default_target':
/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:226: multiple definition of `makefile_default_target'; parser.o:/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:226: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: mmake.o: in function `makefile_rule':
/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:238: multiple definition of `makefile_rule'; parser.o:/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:238: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: mmake.o: in function `rule_prereq':
/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:254: multiple definition of `rule_prereq'; parser.o:/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:254: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: mmake.o: in function `rule_cmd':
/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:267: multiple definition of `rule_cmd'; parser.o:/home/c15/c15osn/workspace/Cprogg/SysN2022/Mmake/parser.c:267: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: mmake] Error 1
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `.c` and `.h` files? You got a link error and your source code is needed to solve the issue. It seems that files are too large, so, please provide only header files and includes.

Comment: mmake:
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "parser.c"`

parser.c 
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "parser.h"`

Comment: And parser.h
`#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct makefile makefile;
typedef struct rule rule;
makefile *parse_makefile(FILE *fp);
const char *makefile_default_target(makefile *make);
rule *makefile_rule(makefile *make, const char *target);
const char **rule_prereq(rule *rule);
char **rule_cmd(rule *rule);
void makefile_del(makefile *make);
#endif `

Comment: 1) [Edit] your question to post the files, because they're unreadable as comments. 2) Your makefile looks fine, it's the link error that's getting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never include the `.c` or `.cpp` file in your code, as it causes a link-time redefinition error.

Replace the `#include "parser.c"` in the `mmake.c` file with `#include "parser.h"` and the error will be gone.

There should be only a single implementation for each declaration. Therefore, when you include the `.c` files, one implementation goes to `parser.o`, and another implementation goes to `mmake.o`, which causes a redefinition error from the linker. However, when you include the `.h` files (note that you should not put your implementation in the `.h` files), you only include the declaration and inform the compiler that the functions or other structures exist but link to the implementation (which is in `.c` files) during the linking phase.